# Representations of semidirect products of non-abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters, semidirect-product

I am trying to define  representations of semidirect products of non-abelian groups following [the example of representations of semidirect products of abelian groups by Etingof et al](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/repb.pdf). Here is what I have.

*Am I doing it write?*

Let $G, A$ be two non-abelian groups and let $\phi: G \to Aut(A)$ be a homomorphism.
For $a \in A$ denote $\phi(g)a$ by $g(a)$. The semidirect product $G
 \ltimes A$ is defined to be the product $A \times G$ with
 multiplication law $$ (a_1, g_1) (a_2, g_2) = (a_1 g_1 (a_2), g_1 g_2)$$.

The irreducible representations of $A$ can be more than one dimensional and, together, they form the character group $A^\vee$ (direct product as the group operation), which carries an action of $G$. Let $O$ be an orbit of this action, $x \in O$ a chosen element, and $G_x$ the stabilizer of $x$ in $G$. Let $U$ be an irreducible representation of $G_x$.

Then we define a representation $V_{(O, U)}$ of $G \ltimes A$ as follows.

As a representation of $G$, we set 
$$
V_{(O, x, U)} = Ind^{G}_{G_x} U= \{f: G \to U | f(hg) = hf(g), h \in G_x\}
$$.

Next we introduce an additional action of $A$ on this space by $(a f)(g) = x(g(a))f(g) $. Then it is easy to check that these two actions combine into an action of $G \ltimes A$. Also, it is clear that this representation does not really depend on the choice of $x$, in the following sense. Let $x, y \in O$ and $g \in G$ be such that $g x = y$, and let $g(U)$ be the representation of $G_y$ obtained from the representation $U$ of $G_x$ by the action of $g$. Then, $V_{(O, x, U)}$ is naturally isomorphic to $V_{(O, y, g(U))}$. Thus we will denote $V_{(O, x, U)}$ by $V_{(O, U)}$.

Comment: It is not so clear to me why this actually defines an action of $A$, since $x$ is not multiplicative.

Comment: (ohh, and the characters of $A$ need not form a group when $A$ is not abelian, and when it is, you need tensor product, not direct product to get the operation).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, what do you mean when you say that the orbit $O$ is not multiplicative?

Comment: Not the orbit. The character $x$ is not going to be multiplicative unless it is linear. And without that, your definition does not seem to be an action of $A$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I think I am having hard time to understand your comments and might be asking really dumb questions. Hope you will bear with me. So, you are saying $x$ is not multiplicative so it does not define an action of $A$. Your argument behind the statement is that $A^\vee$ may not be a group. Which of the four group properties (closure, associativity, identity element, and Inverse element), the collection of all characters of a non-abelian group may not have? Inverse element? I assume the rest three group properties are guaranteed.

Comment: That depends. The way you have defined it, you only consider irreducible characters, in which case there is simply no operation on the set which makes it a group (in any useful way).

Comment: But this is not the same as the individual characters not being multiplicative, i.e. they are not group homomorphisms, and this is what makes your definition fail to be an action of $A$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, why the regular multiplication on $\mathbb{C}$ can not be a group operation for the group of characters? Because of closure?

Comment: Because the characters do not take non-zero values in general. And the product defined like this will not give irreducible characters from irreducible characters in general.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50277/discussion-between-omar-shehab-and-tobias-kildetoft).